# Can't import Pyomo in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyomo

I'm trying to import pyomo in Jupyter Notebook, I ran the following code:

```
!pip3 install pyomo
```

```
import pyomo
```

THEN it came back:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyomo in /Users/*/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (5.7.3) Requirement already satisfied: PyUtilib>=6.0.0 in /Users/*/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from pyomo) (6.0.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4 in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyomo) (1.15.0) Requirement already satisfied: ply in /Users/*/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from pyomo) (3.11) 
Requirement already satisfied: nose in /Users/*/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from PyUtilib>=6.0.0->pyomo) (1.3.7) 
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.0.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-5-7105a3440ba3> in <module> 1 get_ipython().system('pip3 install pyomo') ----> 2 import pyomo
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo'
```

I think I already installed pyomo, but when I try to import the module, it cannot be found.
Please someone helps to resolve this issue.

Comment: is your jupter enviroment the same as the one you are running your'e importing pyomo?It's a common mistake

Comment: see if this one works?: `from pyomo.environ import *`

Answer (score 0):

`import pyomo` doesnt work. as written in the doc you should use this package like:

`from pyomo.environ import *` or like:

`import pyomo.environ`

Comment: I tried, but still shows `
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo'`

Comment: go to terminal ,activate the enviroment.type `pip list` see if the package is there,then type python , to go to python shell and type `from pyomo.environ import *` see if it works.